# How to detect http vs https from an Http.IncomingMessage in node.js

Tags: node.js

Given an `Http.IncomingMessage` created by an `http(s).Server` in response to a request what's the correct / recommended way to detect if the request is http vs https?

Some random ideas that I have no idea are correct

- Check the port

  ```
  // seems wrong - might be using a different port
  const isHTTPS = req.socket.address().port === 443;
  ```
- Check if the socket has a cert

  ```
  // does no cert mean it wasn't https?
  const isHTTPS = req.socket.getPeerCertificate &&
       request.socket.getPeerCertificate() !== null;
  ```
- Check if the socket has the function `getPeerCertificate`

  ```
  // does no func = !https?
  const isHTTPS = req.socket.getPeerCertificate !== undefined;
  ```
- Check if the socket is a `tls.TLSSocket`

  ```
  const tls = require('tls');

  const isHTTPS = req.socket instanceof tls.TLSSocket;
  ```
- other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`req.socket` will have a property called [`encrypted`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_encrypted) set to `true` for HTTPS connections.

Comment: I'm using Next.js and I don't see that property on `context.req.socket`. Should it be present in all standard implementations? Maybe Next.js hides it somewhere else?

Comment: @emersonthis perhaps as an alternative, check if `context.req.socket.getPeerCertificate` is a function, which should only be true for TLS connections (unless Next.js does indeed hide these details).