# How to detect HTTPS vs HTTP in Next.js getServerSideProps

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to detect if the incoming request is using SSL (HTTP or HTTPS).

Next.js exposes an [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) object that gets passed to `getServerSideProps` on the `context` object.

Example:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    console.log(context.req); // This is http.IncomingMessage
    ...
}
```

However I can't find the protocol. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566376/how-to-detect-http-vs-https-from-an-http-incomingmessage-in-node-js), SSL should be flagged on `req.socket.encrypted`. But I'm not finding that property.

Comment: Next.js proxies those requests, so it will always be http, i.e. `req.socket.encrypted` will be `undefined`. Use `req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || req.headers.referer?.split('://')[0]` instead.

Comment: @brc-dd is Next.js proxying the request or is it the host (Netlify / Vercel, etc)? Can you submit your solution as an answer? If it works I’ll accept it.

Comment: @juliomalves My situation is not an API request handler. I need to detect SSL inside getServerSideProps. It’s possible that these two contexts are the same… but until we know that I think this should remain a separate question.

Comment: Both API routes and `getServerSideProps` run on the server in a Node.js environment, the solutions for API routes will also work for `getServerSideProps`.